# Questions on analyzing time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Hi I have some doubts about my analysis on the following two code fragment:

1)

```
    for (i = 1; i <= 1.5n; i++)
        for (j = n; j >= 2; j--)
            cout << i, j;
```

The outer loop will be executed 1.5n times, and the inner loop will be executed n-2 times. Therefore, the complexity is O(1.5n*(n-2) = O(n^2)?

2)

```
    j = 1;
    while (j < n/2) {
        i = 1;
        while (i < j) {
            cout << j << i;
            i++;
        }
        j++;
    }
```

The outer while loop will be executed n/2  times, and the inner while loop will be executed 1+2+...+n/2 times. Therefore, the complexity is also O(n^2)?

I was not so sure about my analysis on second problem.

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I was not so sure if the outer while loop is logn or n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. The right solution is to count.

Note that:

```
j = 0;
while (j < n/2) {
    j++;
}
```

has a `O(n)`complexity, whereas:

```
j = 1;
while (j < n) {
    j *= 2;
}
```

has a `O(log n)` complexity.